# I have an opportunity to interview but I don't feel I have the skills to do the job successfully

Tags: interviewing

I've been given the opportunity to interview for a technical position. However, I don't feel that I have the skills to even make it through the technical screenings. This interview would be for a lateral move. Is it worth going through an interview when you know you have a slim chance of getting the job? I don't want to embarrass myself in front of my colleagues.

Comment: The fact that you are aware of this site seems to indicate to me you are probably more qualified than you think, as a lot of technical abilities come from knowing how/where to find information.

Answer (score 11):

> Is it worth going through an interview when you know you have a slim chance of getting the job?

Yes, it is.

First off, you may actually have better technical ability than you give yourself credit.

Second if the opportunity was given to you by your colleagues, they are probably aware of your abilities - if this is for a lateral move, they may very well think you are well suited for a junior position where you can learn and grow.

Third - it is always good to get interview practice. The more real the interview, the better - the process and interview itself will be a learning experience.

In regards to embarrassing yourself - you say you are not currently in a technical position. The people interviewing you know this and know this is a lateral move for you. This does mean that if you don't show a high level of technical knowledge, it is expected. Interviews are not exams - you don't get scored, as such.

Comment: @aaroncross - You are welcome. More answers will probably be coming, so keep coming back.

Answer (score 3):

Your colleagues apparently recommended you. That leaves several possibilities:

- They think you can do the job. Which can mean the interview may be just a formality.
- They want to start pushing you into a career track that has better growth potential. In which case even if you don't get the job they think the process will be helpful.
- They think you barely qualify, but can hire you easily and quickly. This can help the company by opening your present position to somebody else. It can also mean that they can charge more for your services.

So apply for the position and do the interview.

Comment: Thank you for your answers mhoran_psprep. I didn't think of these possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure they're not putting more emphasis on aptitude then currently having specific skills? It sounds like you may pick up on things quickly and they're better off in the long-term having a more talented person who may take a little more time to get up to speed.

Like others have suggested, take the interview.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely apply for the position.

Apart from this, you can ask about expected technical skills or training opportunities.

In the department where I'm currently working, everyone should have an engineer profile. One of the younger project managers (his job is a very technical one and he deals with partner companies) was recruited without a lot of initial technical skills (he rather has a sales rep profile....) but his knowledge of the company structure and partners and his aptitudes balanced his lack of theoretical knowledge and his work is much appreciated.